# Utility for sending HTML mail with attachments to a long list of emails?

Tags: email

I'm in the middle of writing a Python program which simply sends the same HTML message with an attachment to a large list of email addresses (BCC). Is there a utility I could use to do this rather than writing something from scratch? The actual email message doesn't vary at all, I simply need to send the same HTML and same attachment to all emails.

Does a Unix utility exist to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command-line program such as or `mutt`.
See http://www.mutt.org/.

Edit: have you looked at http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html?

Comment: Mutt is just a client, it doesn't have the ability to send mail (it uses `sendmail` or whatever)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Well ... built-in SMTP was added to recent 1.5.x versions of mutt.

Comment: @jw013 Really? That's wildly un-Unix-y, but ok; nevermind then

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Indeed, the mutt wiki seems almost ashamed to admit it.  Apparently it was a frequently requested feature though.

Comment: I wrote the program, wasn't too hard. I just have to fight my OCD to build "the best, most flexible Python email tool ever."